# Object.keys and reduce

Tags: typescript

I have an object with nullable fields. I want to return a new object without the null values, e.g.:

```
type Item = {
    name?: string
    color?: string
    size?: string
    weight?: string
}

function filterNullItemValues(myItem: Item) {
    return Object.keys(myItem).reduce((acc, key) => {
        if (myItem[key]) {
            acc[key] = myItem[key]
        }
        return acc
    }, {})
}
```

TypeScript complains about:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Item'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Item'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG8BQVtQHYEMEIB%20ALigGdgAnAS1wHMscBjAewBs3qzKb6mOSrQBeJcrgCuCAEYRqzbAHcItBgAtgvKbPkYAvhgwAzSbhbBabXFGO0O8agDlJHDnEQA1fB0kQKABQIIB4I5KEAlOiKUNQQwJLUNgDyMgBWEBYAdADWECCBwZFZcQAmkiwQAQH4LCwANFB5IFHIAHzRQkK0xlBBIfAIANrNALpRmF1TULUsI-mjKFBFg-MgozFChtOx8Yk2szH6EQYYQA)

Comment: Cast the result as an `Item` (put `as Item` after the end parentheses).

Comment: still complains about the `if (myItem[key]) {` part

Comment: `Object.keys` returns `string[]`. You have to narrow it, e.g. https://tsplay.dev/wXyQkN. `null` isn't a valid value for an optional property to start with, though.

Comment: Sort of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as you don't need `.reduce()` with `Object.keys()` here. With that said even this approach has issues like skipping falsy values, whereas I believe you just want to filter out missing values. In addition `acc` is not properly set up for the `.reduce()`

Comment: Not related to the question: If you need to handle both the keys and the values, always use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). Do not separate the keys, retrieved using `Object.keys(foo)` by their associated values, retrieved using `bar[key]`. It works fine when `foo` and `bar` are the same object but from there to a hidden bug is just a typo or a valid change of one of them without changing the other.